# C#: Convert SuperClass to SubClass

Tags: c#, class, type-conversion

I have a class (SuperClass) which is used. For own purposes I designed a SubClass, which adds aditional information for me.

```
class SuperClass{
}

class SubClass: SuperClass{
}
```

Now my problem is, that at runtime I want to convert an instance of Superclass into an instance of SubClass. Do Some operations on it and then back to SuperClass. So my question ist, how is it possible to actually convert an instance of SueprClass into an instance of SubClass?

```
SubClass newItem = superClass as SubClass;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? JGFI... This question was asked here many times already.

Comment: In the code example, is `superClass` a `SuperClass superClass = new SuperClass();` or a `SuperClass superClass = new SubClass();`? If you never used `new SubClass(..)` you cannot do that (without operators, of course).

Comment: superClass is SuperClass superClass = new SuperClass();

Comment: You can 1: change that to `SubClass subClass = new SubClass();` (and everything should continue to work), or 2: create a constructor in SubClass that takes a SuperClass and do `SubClass subClass = new SubClass(superClass);` if you need to keep the data already stored in SuperClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the instance you are working with was initialized as `SuperClass`, you can't magically convert it into an instance of a `SubClass` - that would throw the entire type system out the window.

You can, however, add a way to convert `SuperClass` to `SubClass`, but you'll have to write code for that.

One way is to add a constructor to the `SubClass` that takes in an instance of the `SuperClass` and whatever additional information the `SubClass` needs (if it doesn't need additional information, perhaps you better use extension methods instead of inheritance).
Another way would be to write [explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) conversion operator.

Comment: And there is no way to say something like subClass.base = superClass; I mean subClass.base should be excatly the same as the superClass

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. Do you have a property called `base` in your `subClass`?

Comment: no, in c# base access the base class, it is the same as in cpp super access the superclass

Comment: @Dominick I understand c#, I know what the `base` keyword is, it's your question I'm having a hard time understanding. You wrote in the comments to the question you are initializing the instance of `SuperClass` using a `SuperClass` constructor - Therefor it's an instance of `SuperClass`, not an instance of `SubClass`. To be able to convert it into a `SubClass` you must write code that does that - or simpliy initialize it using the `SubClass` constructor: `var superClass = new SubClass();` Any code that use the `SuperClass` should still be able to work with this instance...

Comment: Re. the explicit conversion operator: adding a user-defined conversion to or from a base type will fail to compile.